# PHP Query in my URL

Tags: php

I am trying to write a peace of code that will change the title of the page based on what is in the url query...

```
?page_id=62&action=register
```

so

```
if(action='register'){
  do this
}else{
  do this
}
```

how would I write this? I have never dealt with this before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) AND $_GET['action'] == "register")
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: add an echo "<html><head><title>".$_GET['action']."</title></head><body>asdf</body></html>

Comment: @silentw Both operators can be used.

Answer (score 4):

Access URL parameters using `$_GET`:

```
$page_id = (int)$_GET['page_id'];
$action = htmlspecialchars($_GET['action']);

if($action == 'register') {
    echo 'action: '. $action .', page_id: '. $page_id;
}
```

Read more about `GET` & `POST` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php). If you want to check if those variables are set use [isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) e.g. `isset($_GET['page_id'])`.

Be careful though, it's easy to create range of vulnerabilities this way, escape/validate those variables (e.g. [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) used it my code).

Answer (score 1):

To read out the "action" you need the $_GET variable. You can use it with `$_GET['action']`.

You should ever use isset to ask if the variable is set or not. With this you can prevent errors.

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'register'){ 
    do this 
}else{ 
    do this 
}
```

Another example: when you ask if the action is set and after that you can ask if action == register or action == login or whatever

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])){ 
    switch($_GET['action']) {
        case 'register':
            //do this
            break;
        case 'login':
            //do this 
            break;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];

if ($action == "register") {
    echo("<title>Register</title>");
}
```

placed in between your  and  tags in your php script

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$title = (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'register') ? 'Register' : 'Login';
```

And in your HTML:

```
<title><?=$title?></title>
```